# optimize get pixel to R G B and long if then else list

Tags: python

I wrote this code that does exactly what is supposed to do.

However since it is enclosed in an infinite loop, and the faster the execution of each iteration the better, I'm looking into optimisation.

```
def get_pixel(x, y, hdc=0):
    dc = windll.user32.GetDC(hdc)
    colorref =  windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc, x, y)
    return colorref


def main():
    while True:
        colorref = get_pixel(897, 632)
        R = colorref & 0xFF
        G = (colorref >> 8) & 0xFF
        B = (colorref >> 16) & 0xFF
        
        if R == 1 and G == 1 and B == 1:
           myaction(1)
        elif R == 1 and G == 1 and B == 2:
           myaction(2)
        elif R == 1 and G == 2 and B == 3:
           myaction(3)
        ....
```

I am quite sure there are better ways to handle:

1. the pixel to RGB thing
2. the long list (about 40 items) of if-then-else

Any suggestion will be very welcome, keyword to search, instruments to use, faster packages, some scratched code.

Comment: The bitshifting will probably be as quick as possible; it'd be helpful to know the logic behind your if-tests to suggest any optimizations. In general, you might be able to make it faster by making less comparisons or using a static lookup table. If the possible values of colorref is only 40 different values, you could skip the extraction of RGB completely and just use the direct lookup value based on the RGB-value.

Comment: If using the third-party [Python Imaging Library (Fork)](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) is an option, you can create images by copying (aka "grabbing") portions of the screen (see [`PIL.ImageGrab`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html). Querying the colors of pixels in an image would likely be much faster than what you're doing.

Comment: I don't get why you are saying that screening and analysing the screen with PIL would be better than using the win api looking at a specific pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with the conditional or splitting into RGB.

The condition `R == 1 and G == 1 and B == 1` just means `colorref & 0xFFFFFF == 0x010101`. Similar for the others. You are mapping `colorref` to an argument to `myaction`.

```
mapping = {
    0x010101: 1,
    0x010102: 2,
    0x010103: 3,
    ...
}
while True:
    colorref = get_pixel(897, 632)
    action = mapping[colorref & 0xFFFFFF]
    myaction(action)
```

Another alternative, if it's possible, is to use a mathematical expression or function to map `colorref` to the argument. You don't provide enough info for a comprehensive solution but something like the following might work:

```
value = kB * ((colorref >> 16) & 0xFF - 1) + kG * ((colorref >> 16) & 0xFF - 1) + kA * (colorref & 0xFF - 1) + 1
myaction(value)
```

`kR`, `kG` and `kB` are some suitable values you'll have to pick.